# What's the correct way to use the CasperJS userAgent function?

Tags: casperjs

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

My code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    stepTimeout: 10000,
    onError: function() {
        this.captureSelector('error.png', 'html');
    },
    logLevel: "debug"
});

casper.start();

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)');

casper.setHttpAuth('user', 'pass');

casper.thenOpen('https://www.google.com');

casper.then(function() {
    this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
    currentPage = this.getTitle();
    this.captureSelector(currentPage + '.png', 'html');
});                                

casper.run();
```

My error:

```
$ casperjs test.js
[info] [phantom] Starting...
FAIL TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'casper.userAgent('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)')')
#    type: uncaughtError
#    error: "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'casper.userAgent('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)')')"
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'casper.userAgent('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)')')
```

Comment: Looks like you're using an old version of casperjs which didn't have `userAgent()` available at the time — your script works fine using casperjs latest master: https://gist.github.com/3303161

Comment: Thanks, have updated and it works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just closing the question, it was a matter of CasperJS version. Nothing wrong here (see question comments by @Niko and @jnthnclrk, the original poster).